Cannot find annotation method … in type 'kotlin.Metadata' after hibernate upgrade
After upgrading to hibernate 6 I see in logs following, while I don't use kotlin. Can anyone advice, what is this and how to fix that?
[INFO] Hibernate compile-time tooling 6.5.2.Final
[WARNING] Cannot find annotation method 'mv()' in type 'kotlin.Metadata': class file for kotlin.Metadata not found
[WARNING] Cannot find annotation method 'k()' in type 'kotlin.Metadata'
[WARNING] Cannot find annotation method 'xi()' in type 'kotlin.Metadata'
[WARNING] Cannot find annotation method 'd1()' in type 'kotlin.Metadata'
[WARNING] Cannot find annotation method 'd2()' in type 'kotlin.Metadata'
...

updated: this is probably compiler warnings which are shown only because:
      <compilerArgs>
        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
        <arg>-Xmaxwarns</arg>
        <arg>50000</arg>
        <arg>-Xlint:-processing</arg>
        <arg>-Xlint:-options</arg>
        <arg>-Xlint:-serial</arg>
        <arg>-AaddSuppressWarningsAnnotation=true</arg>
      </compilerArgs> 

if I comment this out, it disappears. No idea how to disable it specifically if I want to see other warnings.

it's controller by showWarnings element.
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>true</parameters>
          <release>${java.version}</release>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
            <arg>-Xmaxwarns</arg>
            <arg>50000</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:-processing</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:-options</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:-serial</arg>
            <arg>-AaddSuppressWarningsAnnotation=true</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <showWarnings>false</showWarnings>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

